# 398 Directory server access on fedora

Tags: fedora, directory, x-server

I like to install 389 Directory server on Fedora. For the choice, I can install it on fedora server but fedora server does not come with GUI.

1. Is there anything I can do to run 389 Console on fedora server?
2. Or I need to install fedora workstation and install 389 directory server on it.

I may use other fedora server packages like SFTP server, FreeIPA server etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage a 389 Directory Server from the console. However you need to install Java RE 1.6 or later.

Comment: I installed Java on Fedora server but 389-console said I need X Windows system

Comment: `No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
        at com.netscape.management.client.console.Console.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.netscape.management.client.console.Console.main(Unknown Source)`